# Get image from Java spring to show in React

Tags: java, reactjs, spring

I am trying to understand how to get an image from an `Java Spring` back-end to show in a small `React` app.

In `React`, I am trying to set an `img src` to the `image-data` using this code:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState("");
const onClickHandler = async () => {
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/gallery/test", {
      mode: "no-cors", // 'cors' by default
    });
    const blob = await result.blob()
    const url = await URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    setImage(url)
    console.log(url)
}
```

But `console.log` shows this info:

```
blob:http://localhost:3000/620ccbb6-31e5-4a2c-9a61-540beba10d8e
```

`Controller` code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class GalleryController {
    protected final GalleryService galleryService;

    @Inject
    public GalleryController(GalleryService galleryService) {
        this.galleryService = galleryService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "gallery/test")
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImage() throws IOException {
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass()
            .getResourceAsStream("/gallery/test/test.jpg"));
    }
}
```

And if I open `http://localhost:8080/gallery/test/`, I get this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should tell to the browser that content type of the byte array will be jpg image.
You need to change @GetMapping annotation to this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "gallery/test", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
```

MediaType from package "import org.springframework.http.MediaType;" tells to the browser that there will be image in response from controller.

Comment: Thanks, one more question. If I have multiple images in /gallery/test how do I modify the code to send all of them?

Comment: And I am still getting the same result in my React app so I need to modify something there as well

Comment: You can't send images in batch from your spring controller. I don't know any option to do that, only one by one.

Comment: Try to specify data type of blob file in your client code. blob.type = "image/jpeg"

Comment: Ahh, my last problem was regarding to cors. Thanks